# GoldenDict does not see and add .xdxf and .dsl files

Tags: permission, dictionary

Following the suggestions at

https://askubuntu.com/questions/616844/how-to-add-bgl-to-goldendict/1174366#1174366

Goldendict, with file file.xdxf

1. F3
2. Add
3. in the open file window the file does not show as selectable.

I have changed the permissions for the file(s) via sudo chmod 777 file.xdxf. Anything else that could be done?

Maybe it needs to be loaded from the folder ~/dictionary/file.xdxf?

Comment: Some context in what you are trying to do, which steps you are following (including a link describing them if possible) and where/how things don’t work as expected will help to understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: In Goldendict, with file dict.xdxf

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running and how did you install Goldendict?

Comment: OSX Mojave + Goldendict 1.5.0 RC 2.21 (.dmg) The latest stable version.